# Calling a function to create a WinAPI button doesn't do anything

Tags: c++, winapi, button

After a while experimenting with WinAPI, I got a window with a button working. The code was put into my window procedure and looked like this:

```
std::vector<HWND> buttons;
HWND window;

LRESULT CALLBACK CSwindowProc(HWND window, unsigned int message, WPARAM shortParam, LPARAM longParam) {
    switch (message) {
    case WM_CREATE:
        buttons.push_back(
            CreateWindow(_T("BUTTON"), _T("OK"), WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
                10, 10, 100, 100, window, NULL, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(window, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL)
        );
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY: PostQuitMessage(0); break;
    default: return DefWindowProc(window, message, shortParam, longParam); break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please note "buttons" is a HWND vector and "window" is just an HWND initialized with CreateWindow. Context to these snippets are identical to the code at the end of this question.

To simplify what I have, I decided to move the button creation code into a new function (CSnewButton). Then, I removed the button creation code from the window procedure and added a call to CSnewButton(). At this point the code looked like this:

```
std::vector<HWND> buttons;
HWND window;

void CSnewButton() {
    buttons.push_back(
        CreateWindow(_T("BUTTON"), _T("OK"), WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
            10, 10, 100, 100, window, NULL, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(window, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL)
    );
}

LRESULT CALLBACK CSwindowProc(HWND window, unsigned int message, WPARAM shortParam, LPARAM longParam) {
    switch (message) {
    case WM_CREATE:
        CSnewButton();
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY: PostQuitMessage(0); break;
    default: return DefWindowProc(window, message, shortParam, longParam); break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Surprisingly, the button was no longer present on the window. By simply moving the code from the procedure to a function called by the procedure, the button disappeared.
I quickly did some debugging to rule out some problems. I added a message box to the function, and the message box did appear, so the function was being called. The C++ inline modifier didn't help my case either once added to the CSnewButton function. I see no errors or warnings on either compile time or run time either.

So I guess I either have a misunderstanding of C++ or aggressive C++ compilers (I wouldn't be surprised), a misunderstanding of WinAPI (probably the culprit) or something is so very incredibly obviously wrong with my code (I wouldn't be surprised either). Anyway, I would like to know why moving the button creation code into a function takes away the code's function, and a solution to this problem (if possible).

Full code showcasing the problem:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <vector>

HINSTANCE instance;
HWND window;

std::vector<HWND> buttons;

//This function inexplicably does not create the button, however, if you were
//to take it's contents and paste them over a call to this function, it works
//fine.
void CSnewButton() {
    buttons.push_back(
        CreateWindow(_T("BUTTON"), _T("OK"), WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
            10, 10, 100, 100, window, NULL, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(window, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL)
    );
}

LRESULT CALLBACK CSwindowProc(HWND window, unsigned int message, WPARAM shortParam, LPARAM longParam) {
    switch (message) {
    case WM_CREATE:
        CSnewButton(); // Issue Here
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY: PostQuitMessage(0); break;
    default: return DefWindowProc(window, message, shortParam, longParam); break;
    }
    return 0;
}

void CScreateWindow() {
    WNDCLASSEX cclass = {
        sizeof(WNDCLASSEX), CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW,
        CSwindowProc, 0, 0, instance, NULL, LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW),
        (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1), NULL, _T("MyClass"), NULL
    };
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&cclass)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("CSControlApp failed to register window."), _T("CSControlApp failure"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR); return;
    }
    window = CreateWindow(cclass.lpszClassName, _T("My Window"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW ^ WS_THICKFRAME,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 600, 600, NULL, NULL, instance, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("CSControlApp failed to create window."), _T("CSControlApp failure"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR); return;
    }
}

int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE h, HINSTANCE p, LPSTR cmd, int show) {
    instance = h;
    CScreateWindow();
    ShowWindow(window, show);
    UpdateWindow(window);
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code as code, not as images.

Comment: I've got to think it's more difficult to take screenshot of code and upload them into questions than it is to just copy/paste. I just don't get why people keep doing it.

Comment: I'm done. The code at the bottom should not show the button. To make it show the button, take the contents of CSnewButton and paste it over the call for CSnewButton in CSwindowProc. Again, my desired behavior is to have the button show even when called from CSnewButton.

Comment: The changes contain either fake or incomplete code. There is no way for your second code snippet's `CSnewButton()` function to know, what `window` is. Unless there is code we cannot see.

Comment: At the bottom of the Question there should be a code spinet that encapsulates everything (including "window"'s definition at the top of the file). Sorry if I didn't make that clear. @IInspectable Both buttons and window are defined elsewhere. Here, I'll add them to the source too.

Comment: I have guessed the type. I cannot guess, what value it holds, when that value is assigned, or when it changes. At any rate, you don't need to pass a `HINSTANCE` value when creating a window that was registered with the `CS_GLOBALCLASS` style. Standard controls are registered as global. See [What is the HINSTANCE passed to CreateWindow and RegisterClass used for?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050418-59/?p=35873) for an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a C language issue.  You have two separate variables with the same name, and you're confusing them.

```
HWND window;  // This is a global variable

LRESULT CALLBACK CSwindowProc(HWND window, ...) // This is a parameter
```

Inside `CSWindowProc` when you say `window` you get the parameter.  *Outside* `CsWindowProc` when you say `window` you get the global variable, which hasn't yet been initialized at the point at which you're trying to use it.  (The call to `CreateWindow` in `CScreateWindow` hasn't returned yet.)

You can resolve the problem by giving `CSnewButton` an argument:

```
void CSnewButton(HWND window)
```

and calling it accordingly:

```
case WM_CREATE:
    CSnewButton(window);
    break;
```

To avoid any similar confusion in future, it would probably be best to remove the global variable altogether.